# using websocket to access data received by connecting to IoT Hub

Tags: asp.net, azure, model-view-controller, websocket

I am having an ASP.Net MVC App.
This app connects with Iot Hub and receives the message continuously sent from IoT Hub

#### My Requirement

I would like to know what should be the url and prototype to be given to declare the websocket as below such that I can relate the onMessage event of WebSocket

> var socket = new WebSocket(url,prototype);

My ultimate goal is to display the messages continuously received from IoTHub in ASP.Net MVC App on the View(Web Page)

Comment: In the mvc app you can receive messages async using EventHubClient , EventHubReceiver . are you looking for that ?

Comment: Yes Thanks Aravind. EventHub seems to be a solution for displaying my real time data (received continuously from my device) on a graph. I am working on it and get back on how it goes if any hurdles.